# How to use multiple styles for Nice Menus?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

I'm having two Nice Menus, both are displayed in my website's top bar. I created a default CSS layout for them and everything looks quite nice. However, I'd now like to change the layout of the second menu's parent a bit.

How can I set up this alternative style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each Nice Menu can be addressed in CSS using its name. For example I have a Nice Menu called "Product Menu" and by looking at the html of my page I can see that my menu has the following classes

```
nice-menu
nice-menu-right
nice-menu-menu-product-menu
etc..
```

You can use the `nice-menu` class for all Nice Menus, the `nice-menu-right` class is the type of menu it is set as (Right, Left, etc.). You can also customize each menu individually by addressing it in CSS using the `nice-menu-menu-MENU-NAME`